# Processing files with names that contain a "^" (Caret) in Windows

Tags: windows-7, batch

I'm having trouble processing files with names that contain a **`"^"`** (Caret).

What I'm noticing is that if I use double quotes when evaluating the filenames, the "Caret's" are doubled. If I don't use the double quotes, the "Caret's" in the filenames are NOT doubled (preserved), but since some of the filenames contain embedded spaces, I have to evaluate the filenames WITH the double quotes.

As an example, I have a folder that contains some files:

```
G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz 1.txt
G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz2.txt
G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz3.txt
G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt
G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt
G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt
```

I have a batch script that collects the filenames, then reads the filenames and processes each file.

```
@echo off

rem collect the filenames
dir /s /b "G:\Test-folder\ab*" > "G:\Test-folder\list.txt"

rem Note: here I have an opportunity to inspect and modify the filenames as necessary, but I have not found any modifications that solve this problem. 

rem process each file
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("G:\Test-folder\list.txt") do call :work "%%~f"

@echo.
@echo Back: f1="%f1%"
@echo.
@echo.

@echo Running again, with "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion".
@echo.

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("G:\Test-folder\list.txt") do call :work2 "%%~f"

@echo.
@echo Back: f2="%f2%"
@echo.
goto :EOF



:work
rem :work

set "f1=%~1"

if exist "%f1%" goto :dostuff

@echo.
@echo File "%f1%" not found.
@echo       %f1%
@echo      "%~1"
@echo       %~1
@echo.
goto :EOF

:dostuff
rem do some stuff :dostuff
@echo File "%f1%" found.
goto :EOF



:work2
rem :work2

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "f2=%~1"

if exist "!f2!" goto :dostuff2

@echo.
@echo File "!f2!" not found.
@echo       !f2!
@echo      "%~1"
@echo       %~1
@echo.
endlocal
goto :EOF

:dostuff2
rem do some stuff :dostuff2
@echo File "!f2!" found.
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Running this script, I get the following output:

```
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz 1.txt" found.
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz2.txt" found.
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz3.txt" found.

File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt


Back: f1="G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt"
```

Running again, with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

```
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz 1.txt" found.
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz2.txt" found.
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz3.txt" found.

File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt


Back: f2=""
```

So, either way, with or without the use of **`"enabledelayedexpansion"`**, I can't process files with names that contain a **`"^"`** (Caret).

Any ideas on how to do this, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask if PowerShell would be an option? If yes, most PS commands support the `literal` switch like `Get-Content -literal "D:\abc [def] ^ xyz.txt"` which can process files with all special characters

Comment: You could strip double carets from the file names in your `:work` subroutine. To do so, add `set "f1=%f1:^^=^%"` right after the `set` command. There might be better solutions, however.

Comment: @nixda - Thanks for the Powershell solution, I'll give it a try. I am not at all proficient in Powershell (yet), so I was looking for a Windows Batch solution.

Comment: @and31415 - Thanks, your solution worked for me. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it. It's funny, I have used this feature before, and I thought I had tried it for this and it didn't work. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with this for a while, I came up with this working solution:

```
@echo off

rem collect the filenames
dir /s /b "G:\Test-folder\ab*" >"G:\Test-folder\list.txt"

rem process each file
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("G:\Test-folder\list.txt") do call :work "%%~f"
@echo.

rem Note: I still could not make this work with "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion".

goto :EOF



:work
rem :work

set "f1=%~1"

if exist "%f1%" goto :dostuff

@echo.
@echo File "%f1%" not found.
@echo       %f1%
@echo      "%~1"
@echo       %~1
@echo.

rem Notice that the "action" of this (next) for-loop is: [set "f1=%%~f"]
rem which uses the "for-variable" from the "outer" for-loop: "%%f"
rem instead of the "for-variable" from the "this" for-loop: "%%g"

@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo "dummy"`) do set "f1=%%~f"

if exist "%f1%" goto :dostuff

@echo File "%f1%" not found.
@echo       %f1%
@echo.
goto :EOF

:dostuff
rem do some stuff :dostuff

@echo File "%f1%" found.
for %%g in ("%f1%") do echo name:"%%~ng" extn:"%%~xg" file-size:"%%~zg"
@echo.
goto :EOF
```

The output from running this script is:

```
File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz 1.txt" found.
name:"Abcxyz 1" extn:".txt" file-size:"14"

File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz2.txt" found.
name:"Abcxyz2" extn:".txt" file-size:"13"

File "G:\Test-folder\Abcxyz3.txt" found.
name:"Abcxyz3" extn:".txt" file-size:"13"


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz 1.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt

File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz 1.txt" found.
name:"Abc^xyz 1" extn:".txt" file-size:"15"


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz2.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt

File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz2.txt" found.
name:"Abc^xyz2" extn:".txt" file-size:"14"


File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt" not found.
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt
     "G:\Test-folder\Abc^^xyz3^^.txt"
      G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt

File "G:\Test-folder\Abc^xyz3^.txt" found.
name:"Abc^xyz3^" extn:".txt" file-size:"15"
```

I accidentally "stumbled" upon this working solution which uses a method which may be an undocumented behavior of nested for-loops.

I was attempting to use "sed" to change the **`"^^"`** in the quoted string to a single **`"^"`**, like this:

```
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo "%f1%"^|sed -r "s/(\x5e)\1/\1/g"`) do set "f1=%%~g"
```

I mistakenly typed this instead:

```
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo "%f1%"^|sed -r "s/(\x5e)\1/\1/g"`) do set "f1=%%~f"
```

I was not really surprised (at first) when this worked, because I thought "sed" was working as expected. Then, I noticed I had used the wrong for-variable: **`set "f1=%%~f"`** instead of: **`set "f1=%%~g"`**, which was surprising.

I changed it to use the correct variable: **`set "f1=%%~g"`**, only to find that it didn't work.

I tried various versions of this including:

```
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo "%f1%"`) do set "f1=%%~g"
```

none of which worked.

So, this only seems to work if it is "misused" by using the wrong for-variable. While this seems useful in this case, I have a hard time trusting that it will work long-term.

I'd be very interested to hear from others if this is actually a "documented" (expected) behavior, or not.

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to you for discovering two obscure Windows batch behaviors in one Q and A!

It is impossible to pass an odd number of quoted carets as a string literal through CALL in either batch or command line. An explanation can be found in Phase 6) at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053).

Here is an example of the problem. Suppose a script contains the following command:

```
call echo Unquoted ^^ "Quoted ^"
```

After phase 2 of the parser, the unquoted portion consumes a caret as part of the escape behavior. The quoted portion is left alone. The command now looks like:

```
call echo Unquoted ^ "Quoted ^"
```

Upon detection of CALL in phase 6, all carets are doubled and the following is passed through the CALL mechanism:

```
echo Unquoted ^^ "Quoted ^^"
```

The CALL goes through a 2nd phase 2), resulting in:

```
echo Unquoted ^ "Quoted ^^"
```

Producing the following final output:

```
Unquoted ^ "Quoted ^^"
```

Your example with the FOR loop bypasses the initial phase 2 because FOR variable expansion occurs after phase 2.

---

**The solution - Don't pass quoted string literals containing caret through CALL.** Use an alternate strategy. There are several options. I've listed a few below.

**1a)** Don't use CALL at all. You can use parentheses after the DO to create arbitrarily complex code. This is by far my favorite strategy, because CALL is inherently slow. The only thing you can't do is use GOTO within the loop as it will immediately terminate loop processing. If you need to manipulate variables within the loop, then you will need to enable and use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for ....%%A  in (...) do (
  set "var=%%A"
  echo the value of var=!var!
  ... whatever
)
```

**1b)** If the FOR variable may contain !, then you must toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop to prevent corruption.

```
for ... %%A in (...) do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "var=%%A"
  echo the value of var=!var!
  ... whatever
  endlocal
)
```

**2a)** If you really want to use CALL, then do not pass the value as a string literal. Instead, store the value in an environment variable. Note that the value of var is quoted to protect against special characters.

```
for ... %%A in (...) do (
  set var="%%~A"
  call :work
)
exit /b

:work
echo var=%var%
... etc.
exit /b
```

**2b)** I prefer to use delayed expansion so that I don't have to worry about whether special characters within the string are quoted. Note that the value of var is not quoted because the opening quote appears before the variable name within the SET statement.

```
for ... %%A in (...) do (
  set "var=%%~A"
  call :work
)
exit /b

:work
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo var=!var!
... etc.
exit /b
```

**2c)** Instead of writing a subroutine that only knows how to work with one variable, you can pass the name of the variable as an argument. This requires delayed expansion.

```
for ... %%A in (...) do (
  set "var=%%~A"
  call :work var
)
exit /b

:work
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo %1=!%1!
... etc.
exit /b
```

**3)** Use FOR variable "tunneling" as you did in [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/785274/109090). I've used this technique in the past, but I don't like it because it is obfuscated. Someone who tries to maintain the code after it has been written probably will not understand what is going on.

FOR variables only have scope within the DO loop of a FOR statement. When you CALL out of the loop, the scope ends. But, as you have discovered, if the CALLed routine has its own FOR statement, the older FOR variables "magically" reappear.

```
for ... %%A in (...) do call :work
exit /b

:work
echo The A variable is no longer in scope: %%A
for %%x in (x) do echo The A variable is back: %%A
```

The explanation is that FOR variables are global, but only accessible within a DO loop. This is cryptically explained in the built in HELP system. Type `help for` or `for /?` to get the help. The relevant section is about half-way down. Note the bolded word towards the end of the quote.

> Some examples might help:
>
> FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %i %j
>   %k
>
> would parse each line in myfile.txt, ignoring lines that begin with
>       a semicolon, passing the 2nd and 3rd token from each line to the for
>       body, with tokens delimited by commas and/or spaces.  Notice the for
>       body statements reference %i to get the 2nd token, %j to get the
>       3rd token, and %k to get all remaining tokens after the 3rd.  For
>       file names that contain spaces, you need to quote the filenames with
>       double quotes.  In order to use double quotes in this manner, you also
>       need to use the usebackq option, otherwise the double quotes will be
>       interpreted as defining a literal string to parse.
>
> %i is explicitly declared in the for statement and the %j and %k
>       are implicitly declared via the tokens= option.  You can specify up
>       to 26 tokens via the tokens= line, provided it does not cause an
>       attempt to declare a variable higher than the letter 'z' or 'Z'.
>       Remember, FOR variables are single-letter, case sensitive, **global**,
>       and you can't have more than 52 total active at any one time.

That's is as much official documentation as I have ever seen for the behavior. Very cryptic, and not very helpful. In fact, much of the information in that last paragraph is simply **wrong**! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/1012053 for the truth as to the maximum number of FOR variables available, and what are valid characters for FOR variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely not an expert, and hence cannot point out what's wrong in the  verbose program of yours. But I ran this batch and found some intended result:

```
@ECHO OFF

DIR /b /s >list.txt

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (list.txt) DO IF EXIST "%%x" (@ECHO %%x found) else (@ECHO %%x not found)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try as it seems easier than my solution.